# Quran has all answers

Tags: discussion

If Allah has said the Quran is complete and detailed and easy to understand, what's the need for this site ?
Further, you say my question doesn't meet your 'quality standards' ?

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Qur'an is a guide to a person and has all the answers *or guides you to find right answers* - be it religion or worldly life.

To answer your question, this is what the Qur’an has taught us:

> “فاسأوا أهل الذكر إن كنتم لا تعلمون“….ask the people of knowledge if
>   you do not know. (**[Qur'an 21:7](http://quran.com/21/7)**, **[Qur'an 16:43](http://quran.com/16/43)**)

Shaikh ibn ul-Uthaymeen رحمه الله stated, “In this noble ayat is instruction on the manner of seeking knowledge of an affair that is unknown to you, and that is that you ask the one upon knowledge in that affair”.

Hence, the purpose of this site is to bring together the person who has knowledge regarding a certain subject from Qur'an and Sunnah and the person who is looking for answers, so that the person can learn from him.

Answer (score 3):

Quran has all answers, but all people cannot understand all the information of Quran. Many information of Quran are in the form of puzzle and secret and not easy to understand.

> [3:7]  It is He who has sent down to you, [O Muhammad], the Book; in
>   it are verses [that are] precise - they are the foundation of the Book
>   - and others unspecific. As for those in whose hearts is deviation [from truth], they will follow that of it which is unspecific, seeking
>   discord and seeking an interpretation [suitable to them]. And no one
>   knows its [true] interpretation except Allah. But those firm in
>   knowledge say, "We believe in it. All [of it] is from our Lord." And
>   no one will be reminded except those of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
>   course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Read more [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Read this also: [How to ask questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Do not forget to read the whole FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Quran is indeed very easy to understand but our lives are not. When people ask questions on this site they ask about how to apply this EASY QURAN to this complicated life of ours.

Not asking open ended question wrt to Islam is kind of not doing justice to Muslims who seek full knowledge about Islam.

There are many occasions (and this is one of them) where I disagree with the policies of stackexchange. But I respect & hold those policies as a user of stackexchange.

Answer (score -2):

Please think why God has sent both Quran and prophet SAWW.

Quran needs correct interpretation.